# PHP Equivalent of C# string[]

Tags: c#, php

I am new to PHP, and I need to use this web service method in php:

```
Method1(string[] s1, string s2, string s3)
```

Lets say that s1 should be `"x","y","z"`

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean.?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+array

Comment: `string[]` in C# is an array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

Look into php arrays:

```
$s1 = {"x", "y", "z"};
```

More on this: [PHP Arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 1):

It's array, so `$s1` in PHP will be:

```
$s1 = array('x', 'y', 'z');
```

If you need explicitly to use in as a method arguement:

```
public function Method1(array $s1, $s2, $s3) {
;
}
```